# Unexplained error in System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE_Channel?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm going through some application crash dumps, and I'm finding several instances of the following:

> presentationcore_ni!System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE_Channel.Commit+0x62
>   presentationcore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CommitChannel+0xd3
>   presentationcore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Render+0x400
>   presentationcore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore+0x20b
>   presentationcore_ni!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler+0x2f
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall+0x5a
>   windowsbase_ni!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen+0x47
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke+0x5d
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl+0xb5
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode+0x178
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0xa1
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x3b
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke+0x6d
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue+0x27f
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook+0xb3
>   windowsbase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc+0x160 00000000`0016e2c0
>   windowsbase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation+0x97
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall+0x5a
>   windowsbase_ni!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen+0x47
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke+0x5d
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl+0xe8
>   windowsbase_ni!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc+0x164
>   windowsbase_ni!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke+0x50
>   windowsbase_ni!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke+0x50
>   windowsbase_ni!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl+0x13a
>   presentationframework_ni!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal+0x195
>   presentationframework_ni!System.Windows.Application.Run+0x67

Unfortunately, we can't find any documentation or source for this System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE_Channel.  Does anyone know what it is, or better yet, why it blows up?  The error is:

> EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more
>   arguments are invalid

Comment: Drive-by anonymous -1 ftw, lol

Comment: Don't make us guess at the exception type, message and hresult.

Comment: Sorry, question updated.  I'm still getting the hang of WinDbg.

Comment: Hmm, the description doesn't match the hresult.  The hresult is STATUS_BREAKPOINT, breakpoint exceptions can be raised by the Windows heap manager when it detects heap corruption.  Or by windbg of course.  The description points at a programming mistake, in your code and PresentationFramework code not validating arguments well enough.  That's all I know.  Try to get a small repro and call Microsoft Support if that repro doesn't point to the solution.

Comment: The breakpoint its probably reporting is most likely the 'Debugger.Break()' call that we have in our "unhandled exception detected" routine;  is that something that could mask the 'true' error?

Comment: Yes, sure, you really need to know UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject.ToString()

Comment: Is there an easy way to pull that information from WinDbg?

Comment: Actually, its more or less resolved now.  It turns out that the build server has a corrupted/bad/somehow fouled version of the .NET framework;  wiping it out and reinstalling fixed the issue :(